# Find the standard matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $T: \Bbb R^3→ \Bbb R^3$ is a linear transformation such that:

$$
T \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \\ -4 \\ \end{bmatrix} \Bigg) = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\ 3 \\ 14 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ $$T \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -2 \\ 3 \\ \end{bmatrix} \Bigg) = \begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ 6 \\ -14 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ $$  T\Bigg (\begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ -5 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} \Bigg) = \begin{bmatrix} -6\\ -40 \\ -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the standard matrix for T is...

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem.
Could anyone explain how to solve this problem?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996217/find-a-matrix-transformation-mapping-1-1-1-0-1-0-1-0-2-to-1-1-1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The standard matrix has columns that are the images of the vectors of the standard basis
$$
T \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} \Bigg),  
\qquad
T \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \Bigg),
\qquad
T\Bigg (\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg).
\tag{1}
$$
So one approach would be to solve a system of linear equations to write the vectors of the standard basis in terms of your vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \\ -4 \\ \end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -2 \\ 3 \\ \end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ -5 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix},
$$
and then obtain (1).

Alternatively, note that if $A$ is the standard matrix you are looking for, then
$$
A \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3 & -4\\ 3 &-2&-5 \\ -4&3&5 \\ \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -4 & -6\\ 3 & 6 & -40 \\ 14 & -14 & -2 \\ \end{bmatrix},
$$
and multiply on the right by the inverse of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3 & -4\\ 3 &-2&-5 \\ -4&3&5 \\ \end{bmatrix}.
$$

**Spoiler** And the matrix $A$ is...

> $$\begin{bmatrix}-1& 5& 3\\ 5& 3&-1\\-2& -2 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

**Many Thanks** to @MartinSleziak for correcting *two* misprints in comments below.

Comment: What does it mean if the matrix is singular?

Comment: @S.D it means that the inverse of the matrix does not exist

Comment: @john That's certainly true, but what I meant is that if it says something about the function. If the inverse of the matrix doesn't exist, does that mean that there are no functions that meet this characteristic? Or that there is an infinite amount of them?

Answer (score 18):

You can put into a matrix given vectors and their images. If you then do [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_row_operations), this property is not changed. (After each step you have in each row a vector and its image. This is because of linearity.)
If you manage to obtain the identity matrix on the left, then you know the images of the vectors from the [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis), which is sufficient to obtain the [matrix of your linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). (Since you're using column vectors, the result is the transpose of the matrix on the right. It is worth mentioning that some authors prefer row vectors - in such case the matrix wouldn't be transposed. See also the Wikipedia article on [Row and column vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors).)

$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
-2 &  3 & -4 &  5 & 3 & 14\\
 3 & -2 &  3 & -4 & 6 &-14\\
-4 & -5 &  5 & -6 &-40&-2
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & 9 & 0\\
 3 & -2 &  3 & -4 & 6 &-14\\
-4 & -5 &  5 & -6 &-40&-2
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & 9 & 0\\
 0 & -5 &  6 & -7 &-21 &-14\\
-4 & -5 &  5 & -6 &-40&-2
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  1 & -1 &  1 &  9 & 0\\
 0 & -5 &  6 & -7 &-21 &-14\\
 0 & -1 &  1 & -2 & -4 &-2
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  5 &-2\\
 0 & -5 &  6 & -7 &-21 &-14\\
 0 & -1 &  1 & -2 & -4 &-2
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  5 &-2\\
 0 &  1 & -1 &  2 &  4 & 2\\
 0 & -5 &  6 & -7 &-21 &-14
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  5 &-2\\
 0 &  1 & -1 &  2 &  4 & 2\\
 0 &  0 &  1 &  3 & -1 &-4
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  5 &-2\\
 0 &  1 &  0 &  5 &  3 &-2\\
 0 &  0 &  1 &  3 & -1 &-4
\end{array}\right)
$

Comment: like me so; +1.

Answer (score 11):

Note that if $$
\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \\ -4 \\ \end{pmatrix} = -2\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} +3\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} -4\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} 
$$ so $$
T\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \\ -4 \\ \end{pmatrix} = -2\times T\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} +3\times T\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} -4\times T\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} 
=-2T(\epsilon_1)+3T(\epsilon_2)-4T(\epsilon_3)$$ Now do the same for two other vectors to find out two relations written by to $T(\epsilon_i)$. Here, you have a system of 3 equations and 3 unknowns $T(\epsilon_i)$ which by solving that you get $T(\epsilon_i)_1^3$. Now use that fact that $$T\begin{pmatrix}x \\y \\ z \\ \end{pmatrix} = xT(\epsilon_1)+yT(\epsilon_2)+zT(\epsilon_3)$$ to find the original relation for $T$. I think by its rule you can find the associated matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose an alternative way to solve this problem.
There is a neat formula exactly for your case presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)"
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0   & \vec{x} & \vec{y} & \vec{z} \\
            p_1 & a_1     & b_1     & c_1     \\
            p_2 & a_2     & b_2     & c_2     \\
            p_3 & a_3     & b_3     & c_3     \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
            a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
            a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
},
$$
where $\vec{L}$ is linear transformation acting on arbitrary point $\vec{p}$. $\vec{L}$ has the property
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{a}) = \vec{x};\quad
\vec{L}(\vec{b}) = \vec{y};\quad
\vec{L}(\vec{c}) = \vec{z}.
$$
Indices designate components of the corresponding vector.

Let's consider example.
We need such $\vec{L}$ that
$$
\vec{L}: \begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 3\\ -4\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}5\\ 3\\ 14\end{pmatrix};~
\vec{L}: \begin{pmatrix}3\\ -2\\ 3\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 6\\ -14\end{pmatrix};~
\vec{L}: \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ -5\\ 5\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 40\\ -2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now I plug them into the general expression 
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & (5, 3, 14)^T & (-4, 6, -14)^T & (-6, 40, -2)^T \\
        \begin{matrix}
            p_{1} \\
            p_{2} \\
            p_{3} \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}-2\\ 3\\ -4\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}3\\ -2\\ 3\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}-4\\ -5\\ 5\end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}-2\\ 3\\ -4\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}3\\ -2\\ 3\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}-4\\ -5\\ 5\end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Doing determinants I get
$$
=   \left[
   5\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 3\\ 14\end{pmatrix} +
   5\begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 6\\ -14\end{pmatrix} +
   \begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 40\\ -2\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_1 -
  \left[
  27\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 3\\ 14\end{pmatrix} +
  26\begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 6\\ -14\end{pmatrix} +
   6\begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 40\\ -2\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_2 -
\left[
  23\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 3\\ 14\end{pmatrix} +
  22\begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 6\\ -14\end{pmatrix} +
   5\begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 40\\ -2\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_3
$$
or simplified
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) =
    \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 85 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix} p_1 + 
    \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -477\\ -2 \end{pmatrix} p_2 + 
    \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -401\\ -4 \end{pmatrix} p_3 . 
$$
Of course, you can write that in a vector form
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) =
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        -1 & 5    & 3 \\
        85 & -477 & -401\\
        -2 & -2   & -4 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now you can easily check
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        -1 & 5    & 3 \\
        85 & -477 & -401\\
        -2 & -2   & -4 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 3\\ -4\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}5\\ 3\\ 14\end{pmatrix};~
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        -1 & 5    & 3 \\
        85 & -477 & -401\\
        -2 & -2   & -4 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}3\\ -2\\ 3\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 6\\ -14\end{pmatrix};~
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        -1 & 5    & 3 \\
        85 & -477 & -401\\
        -2 & -2   & -4 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ -5\\ 5\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 40\\ -2\end{pmatrix};
$$

For more details on the methods used, you can always refer to "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)". The latter contains many problems similar to this one as explained by the authors of the method presented.