# Find a matrix transformation mapping $\{(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,2)\}$ to $\{(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,1)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Find a matrix transformation mapping $\{(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,2)\}$ to $\{(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,1)\}$.

Is the answer

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& -1\\0& 1& 1\\0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}?
$$

I understand the concept of Matrix Transformation, I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: Of course, you can always check whether you have the right transformation just by applying it. In this case applying your candidate transformation to $(1, 1, 1)$ gives $(0, 2, 1)$, which isn't in your list. (Note that in this case, there are infinitely many solutions, as the transformation maps a linearly independent set to a linearly dependent one.)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313798/find-the-standard-matrix-for-a-linear-transformation

Answer (score 5):

We wish to find a $3\times 3$ matrix $T$ such that $TA=B$ where
\begin{align*}
A &=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
&
B &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Perhaps the quickest way to find $T$ is to multiply the equation $TA=B$ on the right by $A^{-1}$ to obtain
$$
T=BA^{-1}
$$
Can you compute $A^{-1}$ and carry out the matrix multiplication?

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about that. ... It's been a long day.

Comment: What if A is a singular matrix?

Comment: @S.D If $A$ is a singular matrix, then a standard matrix transformation $T$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of the matrix tell you where it sends the standard basis vectors. For instance if I am interested in the third column then I need to determine what the action of our linear operator is on the column vector ,
$$\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right].$$

This vector can be written as a linear combination of the vectors  used to define the linear operator,

$$\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{array}\right]
-\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]
-\left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right].$$

Multiplying both sides by our linear operator $M$ we get,

$$M\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] = 
M\left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{array}\right]
-M\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]
-M\left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right].$$

Note that we know what $M$ does to the vectors on the right so we can just substitute those values in and add,

$$M\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]
-\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]
-\left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]
=\left[ \begin{array}{c}0 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{array}\right].$$

The resulting vector is the third column of our matrix,

$$ M = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
\  & \  & 0 \\
\  & \  & -2 \\
\ & \  & 0 
\end{array}\right].$$

A similar process will yield the other collumns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple method to solve the problem described in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)."
Consider the formula
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0   & \vec{x} & \vec{y} & \vec{z} \\
            p_1 & a_1     & b_1     & c_1     \\
            p_2 & a_2     & b_2     & c_2     \\
            p_3 & a_3     & b_3     & c_3     \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
            a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
            a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
},
$$
where $\vec{L}$ is linear transformation acting on arbitrary point $\vec{p}$. $\vec{L}$ has the property
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{a}) = \vec{x};\quad
\vec{L}(\vec{b}) = \vec{y};\quad
\vec{L}(\vec{c}) = \vec{z}.
$$
Indices designate components of the corresponding vector.

Let's consider your case.
We need such $\vec{L}$ that
$$
\vec{L}: \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix};~
\vec{L}: \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix};~
\vec{L}: \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now I plug them into the general expression 
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & (1,1,1)^T & (0,1,0)^T & (1,0,1)^T \\
        \begin{matrix}
            p_{1} \\
            p_{2} \\
            p_{3} \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Doing determinants I get
$$
=   \left[
   2\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} -
   2\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} -
   \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_1 -
  \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} p_2 -
\left[
  \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} -
  \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} -
  \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_3
$$
or simplified
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) =
    \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} p_1 + 
    \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} p_2 + 
    \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} p_3 . 
$$
Of course, you can write that in a vector form
$$
\vec{L}(\vec{p}) =
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now you can easily check
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix};~
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix};~
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix};
$$

For more details on the methods used, you can always refer to "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)". The latter contains many problems similar to this one as explained by the authors of the method presented.